# select from multiple table and write on one table w3schools

Tags: php, mysql

i want to select from multiple table and write on one table:

```
INSERT INTO interest_area (category_id, user_id)
        SELECT category_id FROM category
        WHERE category_name = 'HTML' 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT user_id FROM users
        WHERE first_name = 'Memar';
```

but couldn't write.

Comment: the table category and user are related by some columns ?

Comment: UNION is not the right way to go, because this will add rows of two tables together. You might want to use a JOIN of the two tables, since you want to create new rows from columns. You will need a column though by which you get the connection between category and user.

Comment: @Fuzzzzel It looks like this table is what creates the connection between the category and user. The above query is intended to say that user Memar is interested in category HTML. It's a cross join, so no relationship is needed.

Comment: OK, makes sense then to just join on the two conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query something like

```
INSERT INTO interest_area (category_id, user_id)
    SELECT category_id,user_id FROM category c,users u
    WHERE c.category_name = 'HTML' and u.first_name = 'Memar';
```

Comment: Please use ANSI JOIN syntax in answers. We don't like to promote obsolete syntax.